# hibernate configurations : connection timed out post inactivity on application end

Tags: java, hibernate, configuration, connection

i'm using hibernate for transactions towards a database. Our application gives an error every first time when we execute a flow we get below error everyday and post that we stop getting these issues.

So my first doubt remained on the fact that somehow we're using an idle connection which has already timed out. Fair enough we can always handle this part using hibernate.cfg.xml.

So i stumbled upon the various ways for doing so i.e. by adding any of below parameters in our configuration for hibernate we should be able to resolve same, however none of them is solving my purpose here of avoiding idle connections which keeps giving me "connection timed out" failure at the start of every day :

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">30</property>
```

The error i'm getting is as below :

```
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:61) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getDatabaseSnapshot(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1520) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.getDatabaseSnapshot(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:316) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:217) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:497) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:735) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:727) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:723) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at com.prod.ecmrs.dao.impl.AuditTrailDaoImpl.saveAuditTrail(AuditTrailDaoImpl.java:34) ~[classes:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) [spring-aop-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) [spring-aop-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) [spring-aop-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260) [spring-tx-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94) [spring-tx-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204) [spring-aop-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.saveAuditTrail(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at com.prod.ecmrs.processor.ECMReportProcessor.process(ECMReportProcessor.java:107) [classes:na]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63) [camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72) [camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398) [camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191) [camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191) [camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:105) [camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:87) [camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:103) [camel-jms-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:562) [spring-jms-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:500) [spring-jms-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:468) [spring-jms-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325) [spring-jms-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263) [spring-jms-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1103) [spring-jms-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1095) [spring-jms-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:992) [spring-jms-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection timed out
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:874) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1145) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1267) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3449) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3493) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:282) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:103) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:230) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:175) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:100) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:85) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:122) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:78) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1179) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1155) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:279) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:205) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:861) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
```

my hibernate.cfg.xml is as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:orcl</property> -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">ECMREPORT</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">600</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTimeExcessConnections">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">30</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.automaticTestTable">conTestTable</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <!--  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>-->
        <mapping class="com.prod.ecmrs.dao.entity.AuditTrail"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.prod.ecmrs.dao.entity.ECMConfigDetail"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.prod.ecmrs.dao.entity.BSCSFUP"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.prod.ecmrs.dao.entity.BSCSRoaming"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.prod.ecmrs.dao.entity.BSCSRatePlan"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.prod.ecmrs.dao.entity.BSCSService"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.prod.ecmrs.dao.entity.OFSPlans"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.prod.ecmrs.dao.entity.OFSPacks"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.prod.ecmrs.dao.entity.CRMPlans"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.prod.ecmrs.dao.entity.CRMPacks"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.prod.ecmrs.dao.entity.ProjectPlan"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.prod.ecmrs.dao.entity.ProductionDumpReport"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.prod.ecmrs.dao.entity.RAITReportDump"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about the establishment of the connection with the database. Did you try to increase the duration of login time out?

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">180</property>
```

Comment: yes i did, i increased it to 600 if you'll see my attached hibernate configuration file

Comment: @Parul, did you fix the issue?

Comment: This was a system issue. As i tried already existing hibernate configuration file on some other server, i didn't face any other issue.